# SSL Redirect Only for Sub-directory

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have redirected all www to non www as well as enabled https/ssl for my website.

My goal is to enable https/ssl for the domain/site on this root level(non subdomain) but enable ssl and well as redirect any http://domain.com/shop traffic to the https://domain.com/shop sub-directory /shop

Essentially all traffic to the site should 301 to http://domain.com and any traffic to the /shop sub-directory should be https://domain.com/shop

Root site is WordPress
/shop is Magento

Here is what I have for my domain.conf in /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
server {
    server_name www.domain.com www.domain2.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name domain.com domain2.com;
    listen 80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include     /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;
    root /home/domain/public_html;
    set $no_cache 0;
    location /admin {
      set $no_cache 1;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        try_files $uri =204;
    }
    location ~* \.(jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico|pdf|zip|tar|t?gz|mp3|wav|swf)$ {
        expires max;
    }
    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        #rewrite ^/my-url.html /my-url/ permanent;
        #rewrite ^/my-url.html http://domain.co.uk/ permanent;
        expires 7d;
    }
    location /shop {
        try_files $uri /shop/index.php;
    }
    location /shop/downloader {
        # rewrite ^/shop/downloader /shop/downloader/index.php; NO
        try_files $uri /shop/downloader/index.php;
    }
    location ~ ^/(app|includes|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { deny all; }
    location ~ ^/(info.php|var/export/)/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
    }
    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }
    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }
    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE base;
        fastcgi_cache phpcache; # The name of the cache key-zone to use
          fastcgi_cache_valid 200 30m; # What to cache: 'code 200' responses, for half an hour
          fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD; # What to cache: only GET and HEAD requests (ot POST)
          add_header X-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status; # Allow us to see if the cache was HIT, MISS, or BYPASSED inside a browser's Inspector panel
          fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache; # Dont pull from the cache if true
          fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache; # Dont save to the cache if true
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*)\.x(m|s)l$ {
            ## this redirects sitemap.xml to /sitemap_index.xml
        rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
            ## this makes the XML sitemaps work
            rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
        rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
            ## The following lines are optional for the premium extensions
        ## News SEO
            rewrite ^/news-sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_news last;
        ## Local SEO
        rewrite ^/locations\.kml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local_kml last;
        rewrite ^/geo-sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local last;
        ## Video SEO
        rewrite ^/video-sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=video last;
    }
    include     /etc/nginx/minify.conf;
    include     /etc/nginx/scripts.conf;
    location ~ /wp-content/cache/minify.*\.js$ {
        types {}
        default_type application/x-javascript;
        expires modified 31536000s;
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
    location ~ /wp-content/cache/minify.*\.css$ {
        types {}
        default_type text/css;
        expires modified 31536000s;
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
    location ~ /wp-content/cache/minify.*js\.gzip$ {
        gzip off;
        types {}
        default_type application/x-javascript;
        expires modified 31536000s;
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    }
    location ~ /wp-content/cache/minify.*css\.gzip$ {
        gzip off;
        types {}
        default_type text/css;
        expires modified 31536000s;
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    }
    location ~ \.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4)$ {
       expires 31536000s;
       add_header Pragma "public";
       add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
    location ~ \.(htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
        expires 3600s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public";
    }
    location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|woff|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
        expires 31536000s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
    rewrite ^/wp-content/cache/minify.*/w3tc_rewrite_test$ /wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?w3tc_rewrite_test=1 last;
    set $w3tc_enc "";
    if ($http_accept_encoding ~ gzip) {
        set $w3tc_enc .gzip;
    }
    if (-f $request_filename$w3tc_enc) {
        rewrite (.*) $1$w3tc_enc break;
    }
    rewrite ^/wp-content/cache/minify/(.+/[X]+\.css)$ /wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?test_file=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/wp-content/cache/minify/(.+\.(css|js))$ /wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?file=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: I think it's easier to just purchase an SSL certificate for the domain itself, subdirectories are taken into account with this too. And your complete site is secured with SSL, only advantages.

Comment: I understand the advantages of having the complete ssl site, but I would still like ssl only for the shop sub-directory. I have purchased an ssl certificate for the domain itself.

Comment: I've decided to go ahead and go for all ssl after reading this https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/09/09/google-to-slap-warnings-on-non-https-sites/

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess of wordpress add the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /shop/
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, L]
```

Comment: Thanks, the root site is Wordpress but the /shop is Magento. Do I need to put that in the WordPress htaccess and something else in the Magento folder htaccess?

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /shop/
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`